# How to verify if DB remote server is running using only java raw sockets [Telnet]

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, db2

I wanted to explore an option to write minimal code to check if db2 server is running using plain java sockets. Just like doing telnet to server. It seems db2 is not configured to respond for telnet connection. Any help?
Below code works for mysql, but not working db2.

> This code is equivalent to telnet ip port

```
Below is the java code

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    public class myApp {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.8.142", 50000);
            String pattern = "mysql|oracle|db2";
            Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[512];
            in.read(b);
            String response = new String(b);
            in.close();
            socket.close();
            Matcher m = r.matcher(response);
            System.out.println(m.find(0));
        }
    }
```

> For mysql2, telnet return some characters with mysql text, version and some encoded ascii characters. But for db2, its seems like telnet is stuck without any response.

Comment: Is the server active on port 50000? Some are not.

Comment: yes, db2 is active on 50000

Comment: If you telnet to a Db2-server on correct port, and telnet shows "Connected to" then it means that something is listening on that port on that host.  If it is a Db2-server that is listening on that port, then telnet __will then hang__ and that is the behaviour that IBM's publications describe for a Db2-Linux/Unix/Windows server.  Your code should not do a read on the socket, after getting a connection, because it will hang (for as long as the tcp timeout I believe) , as would telnet.

Comment: @mao do you have a reference link where this behavior described

Answer (score 1):

If you telnet to a Db2-server (Db2 for Linux/Unix/Windows) on the correct port, and telnet shows "Connected to" then it means that something is listening on that port on that host.

If something is listening on that port, then telnet will first display `Connected to ...`, and `Escape character is ...` . If it is a Db2-LUW server that is listening on the port, you will see nothing further (which looks like a hang). You can then abort the process.

If you do not get a connection (and get an error message) then either a firewall blocks that port, or address is incorrect, or nothing is listening on the specified port at this time.

If it is a Db2-LUW server that is listening on the port, your code should not do a read on the socket, after getting a connection, because it will hang (for as long as the TCP timeout I believe) , as would `telnet`.

The Db2 Knowledge Center should be the first place to [look](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.data.fluidquery.doc/doc/t0070369.html) for details.

If the Db2-server participates in discovery solutions, this can help. Otherwise, connecting to the database is the way to know if a Db2-server is running. That means, apart from drivers, you need to know in advance the host/port, the authentication-mechanism, and any configured encryption, plus any relevant credential tokens/keys/certs/uid+pwd as needed for authentication.

You could also look at the Apache Derby source code, as it implements the DRDA protocol, too see if you can mimic a connection attempt.

Keep in mind that enterprises often have production Db2-servers in a high availability configuration, and often have monitoring and alerting systems that verify constantly that the Db2-server is behaving properly. So consider whether wheel re-invention is useful.

Comment: Thanks. This behavior can also occur if telnet webserver like tomcat. We can't be 100% sure its db2 is the one the listening on given port. which will take us back to square one of the problem

Answer (score 0):

This will still not solve the problem as an tcp server can produce similar behaviour.